# If no value of x satisfies the equation, what is the value of a?

Tags: inequality

> $$2ax-15=3(x+5)+5(x-1)$$
>
> In the equation above, $a$ is a constant. If no value of $x$ satisfies
> the equation, what is the value of $a$?
>
> - A) 1
> - B) 2
> - C) 4
> - D) 8

This is the problem. If no value of x satisfies the equation, then it is not an equation! It is an inequality. How am I supposed to solve this? Isn't the question wrong?

Comment: The equation $1=2$ is well-formed. It just happens to be false.

Comment: The question is fine.  Here "equation" means a problem to be solved.  Find $a$ so that the problem has no solution.

Comment: Simplify the right side , convince yourself that the constants do not coincide and choose $a$ so that the coefficients at $x$ coincide. Then, the $x$-terms cancel out and you have a contradiction and found the desired $a$.

Comment: "Identity" (sometimes "equality") = a statement that asserts that two quantities are equal.
"Equation" = a problem that asks for a simplified description of the subsets of the domain where a purported identity holds.

Comment: @Peter, thanks! I've found the correct answer; it is c.

Comment: Exampling the comment of @Peter, the equation $2ax + 3 = 6x + 4$ can not have a solution when $a = 3$, because then the equation becomes $6x + 3 = 6x + 4.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$2ax-15 = 3(x+5) + 5(x-1)$$
$$2ax = 8x + 25$$
$$x=\frac{25}{2a-8}$$
From here, $x$ will never be a solution unless $2a-8 \neq 0$

Thus $a=4$